# Solving linear equations - Math.LinearEquationSolver returns IO(Maybe[Rational])

Tags: haskell, math

I am writing a program to solve certain mathematical problems, and Haskell is the language I've written it in so far (for various reasons). At one point, I need to solve a system of linear equations, and then use the result for something else. I can give more details if needed, but didn't want to go crazy at first.

The easiest way I could find of solving linear equations was to use the `Math.LinearEquationSolver` module from the `linearEqSolver` package on hackage. Everything works fine, except that all of the methods (e.g. `solveRationalLinearEqs`) have a return type of `IO (Maybe [Rational])`. I want to be able to feed the solution into a method which accepts `[Rational]`.

I know that the whole point of `IO` is that you can't just take stuff out of it and put it back in, but I haven't written Haskell in enough years now that I've forgotten all of what I used to know about IO.

Is there an easy explanation/example of what I should do? Is the simplest solution to use some other module/find some other way of solving the system of equations?

**Edit:** I have tried using the `HMatrix` method `linearSolveLS` but this returns a list of type `[Double]` (and is also nowhere near accurate enough for what I need, even if I did settle for a non-fractional type), whereas I would really prefer the return to be of type `[Rational]` (as in `LinearEquationSolver`).

Comment: I have no idea why `solveRationalLinearEqs` gives an `IO` result. This certainly seems to be an application where the result should be pure. — It can't be too hard to use solvers from other libraries; my [`\$`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.3.2.0/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html#g:10) should in principle work with `Rational`, I just haven't added `instance LinearSpace Rational` yet (but you could fork it and just copy [the `Double` instance](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/linearmap-family/blob/5915be93/Math/LinearMap/Category/Instances.hs#L71)).

Comment: @leftaroundabout it uses external libraries (e.g. CVC4 or Z3) to actually solve the systems, so I guess that's why it wraps the result in an IO. Is the package you linked to yours? I couldn't find any libraries except the two I mentioned when I was googling initially.

Comment: Well, the FFI allows giving the bindings to such external functions a pure-function type, even though the compiler obviously can't confirm that this is valid. (`hmatrix` does this, it also calls externals from GSL.)

Comment: As to `linearmap-category` – yes, I only wrote it last summer, it's (AFAIK) not used in any other projects yet, Google wouldn't consider it relevant. (Anyway Google is seldom the best search for Haskell-related stuff, for general concepts I'd first go for the [hackage package search](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search).) It's also hardly optimised at the moment, so whether this is good for your application I don't know, but it might well be. If you add & test a `Rational` instance, the pull request would be highly welcome...

Comment: @leftaroundabout after I've finished working on this problem I will definitely try to get around to testing a `Rational` instance :) I'm actually really interested in getting involved in the mathematical Haskell community, so might be a good way to start!

Comment: Just curious but why do you need greater than `Double` precision?

Comment: @idontgetoutmuch I know that the solutions will be very simple rational numbers, and for some reason working with `Double` gave me decimals like 0.11423... and I wasn't sure whether this should be 1/10 or 1/9, for example, especially since some numbers that I knew should be zero were given as ~0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to do this is to use `>>=` to combine the `IO` action that produces your result with the rest of your program.

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m  a                  -> (a                  -> m  b) -> m  b
(>>=) ::            IO (Maybe [Rational]) -> ((Maybe [Rational]) -> IO a) -> IO a
```

You would use it like this:

```
(linearEqSolver arg1 arg2 arg3 ... argn) >>= \maybeResult -> case maybeResult of
  Just resultList -> (... :: IO a)
  Nothing -> (... :: IO a)
```

Alternatively, if the rest of your code doesn't need `IO`, you can use `fmap`, or its infix synonym `<$>` to map a pure function over the result of `linearEqSolver`.

```
theRestOfYourCode :: Maybe [Rational] -> a
(theRestOfYourCode <$> (linearEqSolver arg1 arg2 ... argn)) :: IO a
```

Note: Most of these type signatures are just for clarity, and can be inferred.

You could also use the `Monad` instance for `Maybe` in the same way, but pattern matching is clearer in this case, since it is hard to mentally parse expressions that use multiple `Monad` instances in general.

Comment: it's a bit annoying (i.e. makes things more confusing for me) that I have to deal with IO for the rest of my code and use fmap all the time etc. just because this one module has a return type of IO... but as long as it works, I'll deal with it! thanks

Comment: The reason it has `IO` in the type is because it does IO. If you want to ignore the fact that it does IO, and don't care where and when it does IO, you can use `unsafePerformIO`, but be aware that it might cause problems.

Comment: @Tim yes, this is one of the (rare!) occasions where `unsafePerformIO` might be Ok to use. But it's a bit annoying that the library burdens this risk upon the user; well-written FFI bindings should determine what's needed to ensure referential transparency and then offer pure wrappers that are reliable.

Comment: @Lazersmoke I actually did end up just using unsafePerformIO. This code is only to calculate a few examples, and when I have them I can hopefully understand what I'm studying better and come back and write some much nicer Haskell

Comment: I'm the author of the linearEqSolver package. The reason it does IO is because it does solve the problem by calling out to an external SMT solver. (Such as Z3, Yices, etc.) Wrapping it up in an `unsafePerformIO` might be "safe enough," but I'd strongly recommend against it. You are truly making a call to a different program, running on your computer on a different thread. I think it would be wise to keep the IO type in this case, as exposed by the library.

Comment: @LeventErkok great you chime in. I hope I wasn't unjustly critical about your library. Didn't realise what a huge and rather thrilling project is behind that package – kudos! — I'm really not into SMT, so I might be totally off, but... surely, at least this particular problem of calculating, in exact arithmetic, solutions to (full-rank) linear systems is perfecty well-defined and referentially transparent, so no matter if it's implemented through traditional LU etc. or external SMT solving, single- or multithreaded, it shouldn't need an `IO` result? Or do these solvers have global state?

Comment: @leftaroundabout No problem at all; criticisms/suggestions are always welcome. I still think it's best to keep the IO: Depending on your solver configuration (starting seed, other options that you might invoke it with etc.) the solver can definitely return different answers to your query, if the given system of equations does not have a unique solution. Just by that argument, I think keeping the IO is justified. But I don't think anything *bad* would happen if you wrapped unsafePerformIO around it, since the interactions should be thread safe. (Of course, this is a proof obligation.)